# My Debian freezes

Tags: debian, debugging, freeze

I installed a fresh Debian 7 install, but it freezes from time to time, and when it happens (quite often indeed) only the mouse can move around but everything is blocked. All I can do is restart.

- I would like to debug this problem, where should I look?
- I'm using gnome3.
- I have activated X kill by `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`BackSpace` and it does not work.
- `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F2` does not do anything either.
- But I can reboot with `Alt`+`SysRq`+`B`

---

output from `~/.xsession_errors`

```
/etc/gdm3/Xsession: Beginning session setup...
localuser:simona being added to access control list
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/home/simona/.cache/keyring-tnSq4q
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/home/simona/.cache/keyring-tnSq4q
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/home/simona/.cache/keyring-tnSq4q/gpg:0:1
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/home/simona/.cache/keyring-tnSq4q
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/home/simona/.cache/keyring-tnSq4q/gpg:0:1
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/home/simona/.cache/keyring-tnSq4q/ssh
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/home/simona/.cache/keyring-tnSq4q
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/home/simona/.cache/keyring-tnSq4q/gpg:0:1
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/home/simona/.cache/keyring-tnSq4q/ssh
Initializing tracker-store...
Tracker-Message: Setting up monitor for changes to config file:'/home/simona/.config/tracker/tracker-store.cfg'
** Message: applet now removed from the notification area
Initializing tracker-miner-fs...
Tracker-Message: Setting up monitor for changes to config file:'/home/simona/.config/tracker/tracker-miner-fs.cfg'
Starting log:
  File:'/home/simona/.local/share/tracker/tracker-miner-fs.log'
Tracker-Message: Setting up monitor for changes to config file:'/home/simona/.config/tracker/tracker-store.cfg'
Starting log:
  File:'/home/simona/.local/share/tracker/tracker-store.log'
** Message: Stopping applet secret agent because GNOME Shell appeared
** Message: applet now embedded in the notification area
Window manager warning: CurrentTime used to choose focus window; focus window may not be correct.
Window manager warning: Got a request to focus the no_focus_window with a timestamp of 0.  This shouldn't happen!
Fontconfig warning: Directory/file mtime in the future. New fonts may not be detected
Fontconfig warning: Directory/file mtime in the future. New fonts may not be detected
Fontconfig warning: Directory/file mtime in the future. New fonts may not be detected
WARNING : Testing for expected AutostartCondition failed: Got (None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtweak/utils.py", line 152, in uses_autostart_condition
return asc.split(" ", 1)[0] == autostart_type
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

(gnome-tweak-tool:3655): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion `width >= 0' failed

(gnome-tweak-tool:3655): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion `width >= 0' failed

(gnome-tweak-tool:3655): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion `width >= 0' failed

(gnome-tweak-tool:3655): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion `width >= 0' failed

(gnome-tweak-tool:3655): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion `width >= 0' failed

(gnome-tweak-tool:3655): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion `width >= 0' failed

(gnome-tweak-tool:3655): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion `width >= 0' failed

(gnome-tweak-tool:3655): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion `width >= 0' failed

(gnome-tweak-tool:3655): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion `width >= 0' failed

(gnome-tweak-tool:3655): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion `width >= 0' failed

(gnome-tweak-tool:3655): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion `width >= 0' failed

(gnome-tweak-tool:3655): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion `width >= 0' failed

(gnome-tweak-tool:3655): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion `width >= 0' failed

(gnome-tweak-tool:3655): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion `width >= 0' failed

(gnome-tweak-tool:3655): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion `width >= 0' failed

(gnome-settings-daemon:3345): PackageKit-WARNING **: couldn't parse execption 'GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._pk_5ftransaction_5ferror.Code4: GetDistroUpgrades not supported by backend', please report

(gnome-settings-daemon:3345): updates-plugin-WARNING **: failed to get upgrades: GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._pk_5ftransaction_5ferror.Code4: GetDistroUpgrades not supported by backend
Fontconfig warning: Directory/file mtime in the future. New fonts may not be detected
```

---

output from `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`

http://www.fileswap.com/dl/IdLDxQnQ5N/

---

output from  lspci | grep VGA | cut -d' ' -f1 | xargs -n1 lspci -v -s

```
00:10.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation C73 [GeForce 7100 / nForce 630i] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device b04e
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10
    Memory at f1000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 80000000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
```

---

**Solution:**

I think I have solved my problem, by installing the proprietary nvidia drivers, with a lot of help from alex!

My debian has not freezed yet.

Comment: For a start, tell us what desktop environment or WM you use. Then, check `~/.xsession-errors` and `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`. Next time it freezes, try dropping to a tty (hit Ctrl+Alt+F2). Does that work? Can you log in? Also activate a shortcut that [kills the X server](http://askubuntu.com/questions/59594/how-do-i-enable-the-ctrlaltbackspace-shortcut-in-11-10-gui), does that work?

Comment: Can you figure out a way to remove gnome-tweak-tool? That seems to be the devil..

Comment: I have dis-installed with sudo apt-get remove gnome-tweak-tool . By now there is no bad consequence yet.

Comment: Did you try something like `sshd` and connect from another pc?

Comment: I don't know what it is

Comment: google for `telnet ssh`, are services/daemon that you have to install to allow remote/network login, in a freeze like your this would be my first try

Comment: can you post the output of `lspci | grep VGA | cut -d' ' -f1 | xargs -n1 lspci -v -s`.  That will tell us what video card(s) and driver(s) you have.

Comment: Try switching to the proprietary Nvidia driver and see if that helps.

Comment: @Faheem Mitha I would like to know more, how can I do that?

Comment: @simona: See https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers I haven't used these instructions myself, so I can't say whether they will work. In the past I've used module-assistant to compile the nvidia kernel modules, but these instructions may be better

Comment: Are you sure your .xsession-errors is indeed the one of the session which crashed, and not the following one ?  I experienced [similar issues](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=663647) (though Ctrl+Alt+Backspace did work), but usually it triggers a Fatal IO error 11.  Maybe it has nothing to do with your issue though, I heard similar symptoms may have different causes when X is concerned.

Comment: well, actually I removed gnome-tweak-tool and I have not experienced any crash anymore, but this is impossible to say for sure, because this kind of freezes happen randomly. I think I will wait for a couple of days

Comment: Do a memory test (install `memtest86+`, choose “memory test” at the boot prompt, and wait for at least one phase — leave it running overnight).

Comment: I run `memtest86+` and it looks like everything is fine

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use the nouveau driver without render acceleration.

1. Open `/etc/default/grub`
2. Edit the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`

   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.noaccel=1"
3. Execute `update-grub`
4. Reboot